# Understaning construction was + infinitive

Tags: tense, infinitives

From the Godfather book:

> Maranzano's refusal touched off the great war of 1933 which ***was
>   to*** change the whole structure of the underworld in New York City.

What is this grammar construction about? I could guess that it's something close in meaning to ***Future-in-the-past***. But why didn't we use ***would*** here instead of ***was to***?

Or that's something completely different?

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track, but this can also be used in the present:

> The great war *is to* change to change the whole structure...

It could be considered as a short form for "is destined to".